# Angular - scrollIntoView resets after initially scrolling

Tags: angular, js-scrollintoview

I am using the scrollIntoView method on an element inside the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook. If I start debugging I can see that the scroll actually does its job initially but then the page gets reset and scrolled to the top afterwards.

Example:

```
items = [];

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        this.items.push("Item " + i);
    }
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('p')[71].scrollIntoView()
}

<p *ngFor="let item of items;">
    {{item}}
</p>
```

Things that fix this but are not ideal for my case:

- Using `{behavior: 'smooth'} on the other hand works fine but I don't want to use that in my case.
- Executing the scrollIntoView inside a setTimeout(() => scrollIntoView, 100) works but feels hacky?

Any ideas as to why this is happening and if the setTimeout is the best solution or not?